# ReactRedux Nested react-redux Component: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a React component `Basket` and another component `ProductLine`. Both components connect with react-redux

BasketComponent:

```js
function Basket({ basket }) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                {basket.items.map(item => (
                    <ProductLine key={item.sku} item={item} ></ProductLine>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default connect(state => ({
    basket: state.basket,
}))(Basket);
```

ProductLineComponent:

```js
function ProductLine({ item }) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row className="mb-2">
                <Col md={5}>{item.name}</Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default connect((state, ownProp) => ({
    item: ownProp.item
}))(ProductLine)
```

Now every time I am getting this error ***Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.***

I tried adding `key={item.sku}` in Basket or ProductLine or Both but it didn't work. every time it shows the same error. As a result, my product line wasn't updated correctly.

Here is React component SS to show in more detail.

[image]

Adding Key on both component
[image]

Dependencies:

- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
- "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
- "react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
- "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
- "redux": "^4.1.2",
- "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",

Answer (score 1):

Might be 2 reasons:

1- You forgotto recompile it if you are using webpack.

2- item.sku is undefined, null or not unique for each item

Comment: I did recompile several times. Also, `SKU` value is there and unique. You can see it on my attached images.

Comment: if u have a github repo i can take a look.

Comment: I change it to Hooks and Working fine now.